How to filter and sort CSV files with embedded newlines in a column?
I have a big number of CSV files which should be filtered and eventually combined, sorted and get duplicate rows removed.
It is usually no big deal with sed to combine them and remove rows/lines with KEYWORD in them and using sort to sort them descending by date and remove duplicates (rows with exactly the same date & time can be considered a duplicate)...
sed -E -e '/KEYWORD/I d' *.csv | sort -bf -ru -t ',' -k 5

But I had to notice that in one column there is JSON content, formatted as prettyprint with line breaks, which causes sed to choke; not to mention that the , within the JSON also makes sort impossible as the columns of the CSV are also separated by a ,.
Fortunately I can tell that - except the header - a CSV row starts with a 9 digit number (which represents the first column) and ends with an ISO formated date (YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SSZ) in column 5, which should be used for sorting. The KEYWORD appears in column 3 (and additionally within the JSON part) and the JSON part appears in column 4.
Unfortunately I have no idea if it is anyhow possible to tell sed and sort or anything else to ignore line breaks (and , within the JSON part) and use regex like definitions for determining CSV rows and columns.
It doesn't have to be sed and/or sort, I'm grateful for every suggestion how this could be achieved!
The output should be as close as possible to the original, but if necessary prettyprint can be flattened, and if there is really no other way also the columns can be rearranged.
Each of the CSV files has slightly less than 2500 rows and are usually about 600 kB big and every day I get at least one additional file, hence the combining, sorting and de-duplication would be an ongoing process. They look something like this:
ID,"SHORT, DESCRIPTION",NAME,JSON,TIME
123456789,ABC:XYZ,NAME: KEYWORD,"{
    ""name"": ""keyword"",
    ""name1"": 0,
    ""name2"": true,
    ""name3"": [""value""],
    ""name4"": {
        ""name5"": ""keyword""
    }
}",2000-01-01T00:00:00Z
123456789,"ABC:XYZ, DEF",NAME: OTHERWORD,"{
    ""name"": ""otherword"",
    ""name1"": 0,
    ""name2"": false,
    ""name3"": [""value1"", ""value2"", ""value3""],
    ""name4"": {
        ""name5"": ""otherword""
    }
}",2000-01-01T01:00:00Z
123456789,"ABC:XYZ, GHI",NAME: OTHERWORDS,"{
    ""name"": ""otherwords"",
    ""name1"": 0,
    ""name2"": false,
    ""name3"": [""value11"", ""value12"", ""value13""],
    ""name4"": {
        ""name5"": ""otherwords""
    }
}",2000-01-01T02:00:00Z


recent versions of gawk and the one true awk can parse csv. gawk can sort. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45420535/whats-the-most-robust-way-to-efficiently-parse-csv-using-awk

Those ...s in your sample input add no value and make it so we can't just copy/paste it to test with, get rid of them. Also, you say in the first sentence that you have multiple input files to filter, sort, combine and de-duplicate but 1 small input file with just 2 unique rows doesn't demonstrate any of that so it's not adequate to test a potential solution with, we'd need 2 or 3 input files including some lines to "filter" and some duplicate values for that. Always post a [mcve] that demonstrates all of your needs and we can simply copy/paste to test with so we can help you.

@EdMorton: my intention with the ... was to indicate that there are more lines resp. rows like that and to make it easier to spot the beginning and end of an CSV row. || sorry, i can't upload a real example of the CSV files, as they contain personal data.

@EdMorton: well... fortunately it isn't that complicated: all CSV files have the same structure. you could see them as part of an endless data stream i can't control. so i get every day a new file with a few thousand rows, sometimes with duplicates, sometimes not; and the rows with KEYWORD in it are just for maintenance and - if everything runs fine - unnecessary noise at the end. these rows to filter, usually only differ by the timestamp from each other. the other rows to keep may have different values but still all in all the same structure.

I understand your intention with ...s but don't do that as it makes your example untestable, you already show a few rows of representative data so we get that. No-one is asking you to upload real data, just create and post a [mcve]. If it isn't complicated then it shouldn't be hard for you to come up with an example and share it with us. If you don't then either we can't test a potential solution or WE all have to do that work of creating an example to test with and we're more likely to get it wrong than you are. See [ask] and other questions that have been upvoted and answered for examples.

Your code looks like you want to search for KEYWORD - I assume that's the "filter" you mentioned but do you REALLY want to match that anywhere it can appear in the input or only in a specific location on each row? State your requirements for that and show in your example cases where it exists in the right place and so is printed but also cases where it appears in the wrong place and so should not be printed. Should it be a full or partial, regexp or string match? It's always much easier to match what you want than avoid matching simi8lar things you don't want. Put all info in your question.

@EdMorton: sed -E -e '/KEYWORD/I d' indicates to delete every row/line in which KEYWORD appears. if so, it appears for sure in column 3 and might also in the JSON part (column 4), but no mater where it appears, this row should be removed.

Yes, I know what the code you showed does but I also know it doesn't do what you want it to do, hence you asking this question, and so I'm trying to get you to [edit] your question to tell us your requirements and an example we can test them with so we can help you with the right answer as opposed to one that may or may not do what you want for the specific sample input you've provided so far.

@EdMorton: i also mentioned that the code i showed would do what i want, if there wouldn't be a JSON with line breaks and , in it. and usually at least i know commands i use (ideally even before i use them)... so yes, these things are on purpose and not by accident. || perhaps i find some time in the next days to rephrase the question and mention all requirements in code and text.


it doesn't have to be sed and/or sort, i'm grateful for every
suggestion how this could be achieved!

I suggest trying csvkit which is able to cope with newlines in fields. Consider following example, let file.csv content be
number,action,data
uno,ignorethis,"{""A"":""Able"",
""B"":""Baker"",
""C"":""Charlie""}"
dos,keepthis,"{""D"":""Dog"",
""E"":""Easy""}"
tres,keepthistoo,"{""F"":""Fox""}"

then
csvsql --query 'SELECT * FROM file WHERE action NOT LIKE "%ignore%"' file.csv > filtered.csv

creates filtered.csv with following content
number,action,data
dos,keepthis,"{""D"":""Dog"",
""E"":""Easy""}"
tres,keepthistoo,"{""F"":""Fox""}"

Explanation: I instruct csvsql to select row where action (2nd column) does not have substring ignore (case-insensitive). Keep in mind this is looking for keyword solely in 2nd column rather than your sed approach which is looking for keyword in all columns.
After you manage to make filtering work as intended you might add sorting using ORDER BY for example to sort at 1st column in descending order one might change query above to
SELECT * FROM file WHERE action NOT LIKE "%ignore%" ORDER BY 1 DESC

As I am not sort-ninja I do know what
sort -bf -ru -t ',' -k 5

does, therefore I am unable to translate this into SQL. I can only suggest to summon sort-ninjas coven, make them express above sort call to natural language, then summon SQL-ninjas coven and make them convert what was prepared into SQL.
(tested in csvsql 2.0.1)

it means: case-insensitive sort in descending order of lines with comma-delmited fields, ignoring first 4 fields and leading blanks in each field, and only one copy of "duplicate" lines is output. should probably be -k 5,5 if there are actually more than 5 fields

i really like this solution as it is a simple one-liner! the only minor thing i noticed is, that it changes the notation of the date from 2000-01-01T01:00:00Z to 2000-01-01 01:00:00.000000... but as the output should be as close as possible to the original, still better than rearranging the columns or the like. -- after having a closer look at csvsql i figured to add --datetime-format '%FT%T' and BTW i also had to add --snifflimit 0 as mentioned here to stop it complaining about my file.

now i've to check if the de-duplication (and combining) also can be achieved with csvsql. - i guess it's time to dedust my very limited sql knowledge.

oh crap! i completely overlooked, that the 9 digit ID at the 1st column (123456789) changes to 123456789.0. -- to avoid this -I resp. --no-inference has to be added!

You should use a csv aware tool, as Miller
If you run
mlr --csv filter -x '$NAME=~"KEYWORD"' then head -g TIME -n 1 then sort -t TIME input.csv >output.csv


you will remove the records that contain KEYWORD in NAME
for the same TIME value, you will extract the first record (I don't know with criteria you want to choose which record to keep, in case of duplicates)
And at the end there will be sorting for the TIME field


hmm... i really like Miller and this seems to work quite well, but the only thing is that the newlines get changed: the original file uses CRLF as row separator (and LF within the prettyprint JSON). the output has only LF as row separator (and also within the JSON part). and no mater what i try (adding --rs crlf, --ors crlf, --rs '\r\n' or --ors '\r\n'), i can't get Miller to use any CRLF in the output.

don't get me wrong: this is just nitpicking and should work for most cases, but i'm still curious why it won't use CRLF at all... and also because i read a RFC, that CRLF is recommended as row separator.

@DJCrashdummy can you share on gist your file (or another way you prefer), the file with the carriage returns you describe? I could only work with the text you entered here, where the carriage returns are all the same. If you want help debugging, you should always share also the raw data.

in advance: i'm using mlr 6.12.0 on Manjaro -- i found https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/6.12.0/new-in-miller-6/#line-endings and https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/6.12.0/reference-main-separators/#which-separators-apply-to-which-file-formats -- unfortunately it seems that it needs no debugging...

still the question stands: why is (on Linux) "\n always used and not alterable"? especially when CRLF is recommended and i found older versions of mlr which used \r\n even by default! -- so it seems that --rs, especially --ors is ignored for CSV-files, which makes it useless... if that's not just a temporary regression, this should be also mentioned in the man-page like it is for JSON, that you don't even have to bother with --rs and the like. -- BTW: the same program producing different files resp. output depending on the OS is IMHO a terrible practice!

interestingly although it states "CSV IRS and ORS must be newline" and "CSV-RS: Always \n; not alterable", it takes the \r\n as row separator in the input with default settings and not even mentioning any --rs or --irs at all quite well.

@DJCrashdummy okay, since you don't need to debug, open an issue, you will definitely get feedback https://github.com/johnkerl/miller/issues

already done... https://github.com/johnkerl/miller/issues/1722


Any awk can filter.
Any modern gawk can sort.
gawk version 5.3.1 and newer can parse csv directly.

So, the sed/sort code from the question might become something like:
gawk --csv '
    NR==1 { print }
    FNR==1 { next }
    index(toupper($3),"KEYWORD") { next }
    { rows[$0] = $5 }
    END {
        PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_str_desc"
        for (row in rows) print row
    }
' *.csv

or, incorporating clarifications from various comments:
gawk --csv '
    NR==1 { print }
    FNR>1 || !index(toupper($3) toupper($4),"KEYWORD") { rows[$5] = $0 }
    END {
        PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_desc"
        for (ind in rows) print rows[ind]
    }
' *.csv


The OP needs to provide a better example as !index(toupper($3),"KEYWORD") would match nokeyword (or keyword in an undesirable location within the JSON), we don't know if rows with the same date need to be output in input order or something else, etc., but the OP hasn't told us how to handle any of that.

@EdMorton: i hope it is at least little bit better now... || for sure i mentioned the sorting: a CSV row [...] ends with an ISO formated date [...] in column 5, which should be used for sorting. the sort -ru command in my example would sort them descending (-r) and get rid of any row/line with the exact same date & time (-u), so no need for sorting them.

@jhnc: i used sort -bf just to be on the safe side... but as it only concerns the 5th column, you are right, it rather should be superfluous.

You said sort by timestamp but my point about sorting was that you didn't tell us the order for 2 rows with the same timestamp - the input order, the order of some secondary field, or something else.

@EdMorton: as mentioned 2 rows with exact the same timestamp would/should be considered a duplicate and be removed... so there is no need to sort them whatsoever.

When you know SQL, you can use SQLite to import the CSV.
After that sorting, filtering should be easy, even some JSON functions are available
sqlite3 -csv %TEMP%\temp.sqlite ".import so79183230.csv mytable"
sqlite3 %TEMP%\temp.sqlite
SQLite version 3.47.0 2024-10-21 16:30:22
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite> .header on 
sqlite> .mode table
sqlite> SELECT * FROM mytable




ID
SHORT, DESCRIPTION
NAME
JSON
TIME




123456789
ABC:XYZ
NAME: KEYWORD
{
2000-01-01T00:00:00Z





"name": "keyword",






"name1": 0,






"name2": true,






"name3": ["value"],






"name4": {






"name5": "keyword"






}






}



123456789
ABC:XYZ, DEF
NAME: OTHERWORD
{
2000-01-01T01:00:00Z





"name": "otherword",






"name1": 0,






"name2": false,






"name3": ["value1", "value2", "value3"],






"name4": {






"name5": "otherword"






}






}



123456789
ABC:XYZ, GHI
NAME: OTHERWORDS
{
2000-01-01T02:00:00Z





"name": "otherwords",






"name1": 0,




P.S. In above example so79183230.csv is the source CSV-file.

interesting idea to use sqlite for that... but as i have to do that constantly and still need a CSV file as output, i consider this rather as a workaround.

SQLite: How do I save the result of a query as a CSV file?

yes, for sure i know it is possible... but quite tedious.

the entire thing can be a single sqlite operation on a temporary database using commands fed in on its stdin (ie. ... | sqlite3 "") so no more tedious than writing any other script

Here is a Python solution for parsing the CSV.  In this example it just flattens the JSON column so the output is a single row for each record.  Then OP can either process with awk/sed, or use Python to do the manipulation:
import json
import csv

with (
    open('input.csv', 'r', newline='') as infile,
    open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as outfile
):
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    header = next(reader)  # Read the first line as headers
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    writer.writerow(header)  # Add headers to output file
    for line in reader:
        # Convert JSON column from prettyprint to flat
        line[3] = json.dumps(json.loads(line[3]))
        writer.writerow(line)

output.csv:
ID,"SHORT, DESCRIPTION",NAME,JSON,TIME
123456789,ABC:XYZ,NAME: KEYWORD,"{""name"": ""keyword"", ""name1"": 0, ""name2"": true, ""name3"": [""value""], ""name4"": {""name5"": ""keyword""}}",2000-01-01T00:00:00Z
123456789,"ABC:XYZ, DEF",NAME: OTHERWORD,"{""name"": ""otherword"", ""name1"": 0, ""name2"": false, ""name3"": [""value1"", ""value2"", ""value3""], ""name4"": {""name5"": ""otherword""}}",2000-01-01T01:00:00Z
123456789,"ABC:XYZ, GHI",NAME: OTHERWORDS,"{""name"": ""otherwords"", ""name1"": 0, ""name2"": false, ""name3"": [""value11"", ""value12"", ""value13""], ""name4"": {""name5"": ""otherwords""}}",2000-01-01T02:00:00Z

Alternate version to address columns by name:
import json
import csv

with (
    open('input.csv', 'r', newline='') as infile,
    open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as outfile
):
    reader = csv.DictReader(infile)
    header = reader.fieldnames
    header = header[-1:] + header[:-1]  # Example to move a column (last one to front)
    writer = csv.DictWriter(outfile, fieldnames=header)
    writer.writeheader()  # Add headers to output file
    for line in reader:
        # Convert JSON column from prettyprint to flat
        line['JSON'] = json.dumps(json.loads(line['JSON']))
        writer.writerow(line)

output.csv:
TIME,ID,"SHORT, DESCRIPTION",NAME,JSON
2000-01-01T00:00:00Z,123456789,ABC:XYZ,NAME: KEYWORD,"{""name"": ""keyword"", ""name1"": 0, ""name2"": true, ""name3"": [""value""], ""name4"": {""name5"": ""keyword""}}"
2000-01-01T01:00:00Z,123456789,"ABC:XYZ, DEF",NAME: OTHERWORD,"{""name"": ""otherword"", ""name1"": 0, ""name2"": false, ""name3"": [""value1"", ""value2"", ""value3""], ""name4"": {""name5"": ""otherword""}}"
2000-01-01T02:00:00Z,123456789,"ABC:XYZ, GHI",NAME: OTHERWORDS,"{""name"": ""otherwords"", ""name1"": 0, ""name2"": false, ""name3"": [""value11"", ""value12"", ""value13""], ""name4"": {""name5"": ""otherwords""}}"


Another option would be to flatten the JSON messages so tools like sort can be used.
Problem is that the JSON field is not the last field of the line, so I moved the TIME field to the first place, making the JSON field the last field.
gawk -F "," 'BEGIN{ a=0;line="" }
   /^ID/ && /TIME$/{ print TIME,ID,"SHORT, DESCRIPTION",NAME,JSON }
   /[{}]/{ a=a+gsub(/{/,$0)-gsub(/}/,$0);}
   { gsub(/[\r\n]/,"",$0); line=line $0 }
   a==0{ printf("%s,",$NF); gsub(","$NF,"",line); printf("%s\n", line); line="" }
   END { print line } ' so79183230.csv

output:
TIME,ID,"SHORT, DESCRIPTION",NAME,JSON
2000-01-01T00:00:00Z,123456789,ABC:XYZ,NAME: KEYWORD,"123456789,ABC:XYZ,NAME: KEYWORD,"{    ""name"": ""keyword"",    ""name1"": 0,    ""name2"": true,    ""name3"": [""value""],    ""name4"":     ""name4"": {        ""name5"": ""keyword""        }}""
2000-01-01T01:00:00Z,123456789,"ABC:XYZ, DEF",NAME: OTHERWORD,"123456789,"ABC:XYZ, DEF",NAME: OTHERWORD,"{    ""name"": ""otherword"",    ""name1"": 0,    ""name2"": false,    ""name3"": [""value1"", ""value2"", ""value3""],    ""name4"":     ""name4"": {        ""name5"": ""otherword""        }}""
2000-01-01T02:00:00Z,123456789,"ABC:XYZ, GHI",NAME: OTHERWORDS,"123456789,"ABC:XYZ, GHI",NAME: OTHERWORDS,"{    ""name"": ""otherwords"",    ""name1"": 0,    ""name2"": false,    ""name3"": [""value11"", ""value12"", ""value13""],    ""name4"":     ""name4"": {        ""name5"": ""otherwords""        }}""

